# Deploy website from a Windows XP Desktop

Tags: asp.net, publish

On my Windows XP desktop, I have a fairly simple ASP.NET targetting .net 4 in Visual Studio 2010. I can run it on my local host by ctrl + F5, it works all fine.

I have a Windows Server 2003, that I can access via mstsc, but also via Explorer. When I go to the publish section of my build properties, i see 4 publish methods :

**Web Deploy**, **FTP**, **File System**, **FPSE**

I have already installed IIS 6 successfully on the Windows Server, and given all authorizations for everything I could so far (to get things to work in the first place, will check on that later).

How should I proceed to publish to that remote machine ? Should I target a specific folder ? Do I need to setup things in IIS 6 for that site first ? Or will it all get settled from te properties I have in Visual Studio ?

Thank you guys,
J.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I've always plumped for a manual deployment; that is I create the Web Site in IIS creating an appropriate AppPool and targeting the correct .NET version to utilise.  From there simply copy (xcopy if you will) the appropriate files over, e.g. DLL and all supporting pages such as ASPX, CSS and associated images.  In most situations where I have direct / RDP access this is what I run with.

That said, this can be automated from Visual Studio and this can be useful for those situations where you're maintaining an awful lot of sites on a regular basis.  With IIS 6 and Visual Studio, this was achieved by installing FrontPage Extensions on the server then utilising the Publish option.

For VS2010 it seems this has been streamlined using the [IIS Web Deploy module](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/1022/how-to-configure-a-site-for-publishing-with-web-deploy/) and [configuring the Studio to publish](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/1081/building-a-web-deploy-package-from-visual-studio-2010/) in this manner that looks mildly quick...

HTH

Comment: I've tried copying manually the files. I can see pictures, or plain HTML and so on, but I can't execute aspx pages. I get HTTP 404 errors. But I am sure that I authorized asp pages... Any common mistake there ?

Comment: A few things to look at...Is .NET installed on the server?  Has ASP.NET been 'enabled' in the Web Service Extensions in that IIS instance.  Have you selected a .NET framework to utilise in the Web Site properties for your site?

Answer (score 1):

I've never used the Web Deploy feature in 2010, so I can't really tell you about its merits or drawbacks.  I've read that it works much better with IIS7 than IIS6.  If you have direct access to the IIS root folder on the server (typically c:\inetpub\wwwroot) through a network share I would recommend doing the file system deployment.  FPSE works as well if you have to publish to the server through a remote URL, but there are some security issues with FPSE that make enabling it on your web server a less than ideal choice.

Once the files have been deployed, all that should be left is to configure the website as an application inside of IIS.

1. Remote in to the web server and open IIS
2. Right-click **Default Web Site** and choose properties (if you've deployed to a subfolder in the root, then locate that folder and choose those properties instead
3. Switch to the **Home Directory** tab (Just 'Directory' for a subfolder)
4. Look for the **Application Settings** section and click the button that says **Create**
5. Optional: Select an app pool if you have created a custom one from the default

That should enable IIS to execute your .aspx files inside of your application.  Once you've successfully configured the app for the first time, you can just keep publishing your app to the same location over and over without having to reconfigure it.